# How to send an email to EC2 instances using python & twisted

Tags: python, email, amazon-ec2, twisted

I implemented a python SMTP server and client, using `Twisted`. When I test both of them locally, i.e., using localhost everything works perfectly. However, I want to check it in a distributed environment. Thus, I run an EC2 Amazon instance, on which I started my SMTP server as an application, as showed below

```
factory = StdoutSMTPFactory("./tmp/mail")
tcp_server = internet.TCPServer(2500, factory)
application = service.Application("SMTPServer")
tcp_server.setServiceParent(application)
```

where `StdoutSMTPFactory` is my implementation of a factory building my SMTP server. 
My SMTP client looks as below:

```
import sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.mail.smtp import sendmail
from twisted.python import log

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

host = "ec2-X-X-X-X.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
sender = "secretsender@example.com"
recipients = ["ubuntu@ec2-X-X-X-X.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]

msg = MIMEText("""Test message
from SenderX
""")
msg["Subject"] = "Title"
msg["From"] = '"Secret Sender" <%s>' % (sender,)
msg["To"] = ", ".join(recipients)

deferred = sendmail(host, sender, recipients, msg.as_string(), port=2500)
deferred.addBoth(lambda result: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

where `ec2-X-X-X-X.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` is, of course, a valid hostname of my EC2 instance, just obscured for the post. 
When I try to send an email to my instance I obtain the following:

```
[-] Log opened.
[-] Starting factory <twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTPSenderFactory instance at 0x10815d638>
[Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 5
[Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 4
[Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 3
[Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 2
[Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 1
[-] Stopping factory <twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTPSenderFactory instance at 0x10815d638>
[-] Main loop terminated.
```

There are no errors, neither on the server or client side. Just it seems that the client cannot connect to the server. Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have in your code:

```
deferred.addBoth(lambda result: reactor.stop())
```

This is the Deferred equivalent of the synchronous Python code:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
reactor.stop()
```

If you want to see the error, do something with the argument passed to the errback on your Deferred.

```
from twisted.logger import Logger
logger = Logger()

deferred.addErrback(partial(logger.failure, "sending mail"))
deferred.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
```

Or perhaps consider using `react`

```
from twisted.internet.task import react

def main(reactor):
    ...
    return sendmail(host, sender, recipients, msg.as_string(), port=2500)

react(main, [])
```

which will do the error reporting for you.